# Smooth Scroll Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking to have 100% height on two divs side by side. I want to keep each div independent in scrolling content in each but in the blue div/column, I would like to have a smooth scroll feature. It works now but you will see the red column does not retain its 100% column height.

Thanks for any insight...

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('a').click(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#sectionb").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });



<div id="adiv" style="height: 100%; float:left; position: relative; width: 30%; background: red;">
A
</div>
<div id="bdiv" style=" position: relative; background: blue; overflow: auto">
<a href="#sectionb">Click Me</a>
<section>
 Section A
</section>

<section>
  <div id="sectionb">
    Section B
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1grxdw5/12/)

Comment: There is no link to your example

Comment: Like this? https://benfrain.com/playground/scroll-test.html? Explained here: https://benfrain.com/independent-scrolling-panels-body-scroll-using-just-css/.  Sorry for the external links, I recommend you transpose it to a proper answer here incase the link stops working.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, newbie trying to figure out the jsfiddle link... phew... it's rough but I know how to have independent column scrolling. I just can't figure out how to have a smooth scroll link from my jsFiddle example

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
            $('a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#bdiv').animate({
                "margin-top": "-" + $("#sectionb").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
});
$(document.body).css({"overflow": "hidden"}); // No scrollbar
```

```css
body, html {height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

a {color: #FFF}
section {height: 700px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adiv" style="height: inherit; float:left; position: relative; width: 30%; background: red;">
A
</div>
<div id="bdiv" style=" position: absolute; left: 30%; background: blue; overflow-y: scroll; width: 70%;">
  <section id="sectiona">
     <a href="#sectionb">Section B</a>
     <br>
     Section A
  </section>
  <section id="sectionb">
    <a href="#sectiona">Section A</a>
    <br>
    Section B
  </section>
</div>
```

100% means 100% of the current screen's height/width so it stretches to the height of the current screen, but here is a solution to make the red area the exact same height as the blue area.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, the red column seems to also be scrolling as well. Maybe this just isn't possible?